# Heatmap using latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: python, heatmap, latitude-longitude, analysis, traffic

I have a very large dataframe of +10Million rows containing information about route points of vessels in maritime traffic. I wanted to create a heatmap to highlight the areas with higher traffic flow using python but I am kinda lost doing so.

I've tried a few things, but some options just take to long to run or visualization is not very good.

Does anyone know a good way to approach this dataframe. I was thinking of dividing the map on squares and having the option to regulated the number of squares to use.

If anyone has a recommendation I'm open to it.

I've tried a few things, but some options just take to long to run or visualization is not very good.

Does anyone know a good way to approach this dataframe. I was thinking of dividing the map on squares and having the option to regulated the number of squares to use.

If anyone has a recommendation I'm open to it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.